# Cannot reference from XML to custom @drawable resource in Android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, drawable

Does any body know how to add custom png files and give reference to them from XML file like

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left"
```

Android studio cant find any suggestions when i'm trying to type XML attirubute written below. So how should i import custom resource files/packages in Android studio so it adds references to them in R.java?

Comment: first place to look for android help is her: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html